# Restrict access to page for anonymous users in Drupal

Tags: drupal

Very simple question that i'm stuck with.

I'm making a very simple 'classifieds' website; i have a content-type of type 'classified' i'd like to give access to that content-type for registered users only; i edited the permissions so only 'authenticated' users can 'create classified' and also created a menu link to 'node/add/classified'.

The problem is that when anonymous, i don't see the 'create classified' menu link (right, because the user doesn't have the right to 'create' one) but I still want this menu item to appear and i'm redirecting to my custom 403 page that says 'hey, you have to create an account first before posting a classified'.

What's the best 'elegant' way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you also help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107212/how-to-implement-category-based-newsletter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually done the same thing for a classified ad system. Creating absolute URLs as menu items works for me and is quite simple.

For example, instead of making the menu item path 'node/add/classified', set the path to 'http://example.com/node/add/classified'.  When you click the menu item when logged out (as anonymous), Drupal will try to go to the create classified page, but will fail the permissions check and redirect to your custom 403 page.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to create a new page (via hook_menu) at, say "classified/add".  In this page, check the user's id = if it's 0, then display your friendly message about joining the site.

If they aren't 0, then append/return `node_add('classified')`.  (Note that node_add is in node.pages.inc, so you'll want to include that when needed.)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try creating a new menu item manually (Admin > Site building > Menus > *Menu name* > Add item), to point to the node/add/classified URL.</strike>

Update: You could try linking to */node/403*?destination=node/add/classified (where *node/403* is your custom 403 error page).

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sorry for the wrong answer, I hadn't had my morning caffeine yet.