# Drupal subscriptions to taxonomy only

Tags: drupal, subscriptions

Playing around with the subscriptions module; i have some troubles getting it to send the right notification for right subscription.

Here's the situation :

- I have a content-type of type 'work'; it has a cck-taxonomy field; when creating the content users choses one category in which his 'work' fulfills.
- In user profil, under Categories (user/3/subscriptions/taxa) I choose two categories, lets say 'house work' and 'car work'.
- When creating a new 'work' content I do not get the notification.

But, when manually select 'content-type' in user's profile of type 'work' I get the notification e-mail but independant to which 'category' i had chosen.

This is quite annoying since I only want the user to receive his notifications upon the taxonomy he has chosen, not for *every* new content of type 'work'.

Am I missing something obvious here ?

Comment: When creating a node, in the 'Publishing options' fieldset, is 'Send subscriptions notifications' checked?

Answer (score 0):

i have made it working fine for a taxonomy using the settings provided by the module. Concerning the rights i only allowed 'Subscribe to taxonomy terms '